# How to insert a current date to oracle database using java

Tags: java, oracle

I have a table in **oracle** with a column of **Date** type which accepts date in below format,how to get a current date and insert it with a mentioned format using **java** to database.

**10/28/2015 3:15:38 PM**

Comment: With sysdate? Or do you particularly want to generate the date on the Java side?

Comment: I am going to insert the current time using java to DB but if i can use the sysdate on the oracle side will be perfect otherwise in my java file also is fine. preparedStatement.setString(37,"F");
preparedStatement.setTimestamp(4,sysdate);
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

Answer (score 3):

Just use `sysdate` when inserting:

```
Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
stmt.executeUpdate("insert into some_table (date_column) values (sysdate)");
connection.commit();
```

This will use the "current time" on the server where Oracle is running:

Alternatively using the "current time" from the client:

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(
        "insert into some_table (date_column) values (?)");
pstmt.setTimestamp(1, new java.sql.Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
pstmt.executeUpdate();
connection.commit();
```

As you can see: no "format" is required for this. This is because `DATE` (or `timestamp`) columns do **not** have "a format". Any format you see is applied by the application *displaying* the date (or timestamp). And because dates do **not** have a format, you don't need to worry about the "format" when inserting the values.

Comment: Both solutions are good but how to use the first one (sysdate on the server where oracle is running) in my java class with preparedStatement ? it doesnt recognize the sysdate...        preparedStatement.setString(14,serviceCode);
preparedStatement.setString(37,"F");
preparedStatement.setTimestamp(4,sysdate);
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

Comment: @Peter: plain and simple: you can't do it that way. If you want to use `sysdate` you can't have a parameter (`?`) for that column.

Comment: @Peter - you don't bind sysdate as a parameter; you have it as part of the main SQL string, as shown in the first example. sysdate doesn't mean anything to Java. You're mixing up the two parts of the answer.

Comment: It worked,thanks for your support.